Display error message and character count in same line below in lwc
I have a requirement to display a character count underneath an input field, which is a required field. However, I'm encountering an issue: when the user does not input anything and the error message appears, it pushes the character count far below the input field, as shown in the attached image.
Below is my existing code. Could someone help me how i can have both the character count and error message stay on the same line when the error message appears?
    <div class="ac-input">
        <h2>Project Name</h2><span class="required-label">Required</span>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
            <lightning-input type="text" label="Name" variant="label-hidden"
            value={apeName}
            placeholder={namePlaceholder}
            message-when-too-long={nameMaxLengthError}
            message-when-value-missing={nameMissingError}
            onchange={handleNameChange} max-length="255" required></lightning-input>

            <div class="character-count-container">
                <p class="character-count">{nameCharactersLeft} characters left</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ac-input">
        <h2>Project Description</h2>
        <lightning-textarea name="description" label="Project Description" variant="label-hidden"
        value={apeDescription} 
        placeholder={descriptionPlaceholder}
        message-when-too-long={descriptionMaxLengthError}
        onchange={handleDescriptionChange} maxlength="500"></lightning-textarea>
        <div class="character-count-container">
            <p class="character-count">{descriptionCharactersLeft} characters left</p>
        </div>
    </div> 



.required-label
{
  padding-left:8px;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  font-family: PublicSans-Italic;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:italic;
  font-weight:normal;
}

.button-spacing{
  padding-bottom:12px;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.character-count-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  bottom: -20px;
}

.character-count {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  font-family: PublicSans-Regular;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-left: auto;
}
 

